# how to make the offset drop line while the lines aren't the same length?

Tags: python, file, offset, seek

```
def load_from_file():
    d = {}  # create empty dict 
    file = open("players.txt", "r")# open file for reading
    line = file.readline()
    file.close()# we’re done with the file
    list = line.split(",")
    prop = {"position":"","number":"","name":"","birth":"","id":""}
    keys = (sorted(prop))
    num = 0
    for key in keys:
        d[key] = list[num]
        num += 1
    return d
```

The problem is that whenever the loop returns to this function it reads the same line! and i want the offset to drop a new line

Comment: What is *"the offset"*?

Comment: You read one line, then close the file. Read each line from the file [as the documentation says](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) and do what you want with it.

Comment: can you show me how?

Comment: This isn't really a tutorial site. There is adequate documentation. Try something and ask a question if you get stuck.

Comment: Take a look at [**`csv`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) particularly [**`DictReader`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're telling the program to only read the first line of the file every time you call the function at the [file.readline()](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects) statement.  You should read all the file in at once into a list, then loop through the lines that have been read into the list.

Example:

```
def load_from_file():
    with open("players.txt", "r") as myfile # open file for reading
       myfile = file.readlines()
    return myfile

def create_dictionary(line):
    d = {}
    list = line.split(",")
    prop = {"position":"","number":"","name":"","birth":"","id":""}
    keys = (sorted(prop))
    num = 0
    for key in keys:
       d[key] = list[num]
       num += 1
    return d

data = []
filedata = load_from_file()
for line in filedata:
    data.append(create_dictionary(line))
```

P.S.  Not sure what all you're trying to do with data, but this should help you get the gist.

Comment: @Peter Wood, not necessary but way less complicated particularly with the way he was open the file every time in the function.  Easier to operate on Python lists instead of handling file pointers.

Comment: `for line in myfile` isn't complicated

Answer (score 0):

Using [**`DictReader`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader) from the [**`csv`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module:

```
def load_from_file():
    with open("players.txt") as players:
        fields = ["birth", "id", "name", "number", "position"]
        reader = csv.DictReader(players, fields)
        return list(reader)
```